# ros2: error: unrecognized arguments: --qos-profile-overrides-path profile.yaml

Tags: python, ros2

I'm using the ROS2 eloquent dist. When I'm trying to play the rosbag with the above command I'm getting the below error

```
ros2: error: unrecognized arguments: --qos-profile-overrides-path profile.yaml
```

command I'm using:

`ros2 bag record sample.bag  --qos-profile-overrides-path /home/ubuntu/profile.yaml`

Could you please help me to understand the issue here

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify topics when recording and use the `-o` flag for designating an output file.

`ros2 bag record -a -o sample.bag  --qos-profile-overrides-path /home/ubuntu/profile.yaml`

Comment: I have specified the topic in the profile.yaml file  and tried the same command, but still getting the same error

Comment: @harika when recording you cannot specify topics to record *just* in the yaml file. You **have** you use the syntax that I did above; i.e. include `-o` and `-a`(or a topic listing)